# Angular 9 - PUT requests are not sending the body

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, http

```js
// any component
async submit(value: any) {
  await this.guildService.saveGuild(this.guild.id, value);
}
...
// guild.service.ts
saveGuild(id: string, value: any) {
  return this.http.put(`${this.endpoint}/${id}?key=${this.key}`, value).toPromise();
}
```

API route

```js
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {        
        const id = req.params.id;
        validateGuildManager(req.query.key, id);

        const updatedGuild = await SavedGuild.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body).lean();

        res.json(updatedGuild);
    } catch { res.status(400).send('Bad Request'); }
});
```

I've tried many different `value` combinations but the body is undefined on the API.

Repo: https://github.com/theADAMJR/2pg-dashboard - commit not included, but issue persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have a body parser middleware. Without using a body parser body will always be null/undefined.

The angular side looks fine to me, you can verify by looking at the request in the browser network requests tab and observing that the request body is present

For express try https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

For koa try
https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-bodyparser

Comment: I forgot body parser. Thank you!